# how to add an id to an data-id element in javascript/jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've searched for a solution to select a data-id in jquery and add an id to it.
So far I could find any solution working in my case,

My code:

```js
(function() {
    $('[data-id="row_34571"]:nth-child(n+2)').attr("id","example");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

so, what I want with this code is automatic select all child objects of my data-id execpt for child 1, and give it an id named example.

All solutions are welcome.

Comment: what happens after running code do? any error or not

Comment: No, nothing happens. I guess my selector is not working but I can't find how to fix it.

Comment: We can't really help you to fix a selector without seeing the HTML structure. Note that the logic here, if it worked, would be adding duplicate `id` attributes, which is invalid. Also note that you're missing the `$` from the start so this code will be running before the DOM is loaded fully, which is most likely the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> what I want with this code is automatic select all child objects of my data-id execpt for child 1

I found the solution for you:

```
$('[data-id]:not(:nth-of-type(1))').attr("id","example");
```

Example:

```js
$('[data-id]:not(:nth-of-type(1))').text("This is Not the first one (Selected by jQuery");
```

```css
[data-id]:not(:nth-of-type(1)) {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-id="foo">The First one</div>
<div data-id="foo"></div>
<div data-id="foo"></div>
<div data-id="foo"></div>
<div data-id="foo"></div>
<div data-id="foo"></div>
```

Comment: That is what i mean, yes. but when i run it nothing happens.

Comment: @RamondeVries I edited my answer. Look at it again. now it works.

Comment: The code that i use won't work with this type of solution, ill still keep this up since your solution is working when using it your way. I've found my solution by creating a new post type. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try :

```
$('[data-id] .childElement').not(":first").attr("id","example");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
(function() {
     $("[data-id="row_34571"]:not(:first-child)").attr("id","example");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are expecting this kind of solution. According to my understanding, this is a sample,

```js
$('#change').click(function(){
 var divs = $('#container > div:not(:first-child)');
  $(divs).each(function(){
      var dataId =  $(this).attr('data-id');
      $(this).attr('id','example');
      
     alert($(this).attr('id'));
  })



})
```

```css
#container>div{
padding:10px;
border:1px solid green;
background-color:#f7f7f7;
margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div data-id="row1" id="1"></div>
  <div data-id="row2" id="2"></div>
  <div data-id="row3" id="3"></div>
  <div data-id="row4" id="4"></div>
  <div data-id="row5" id="5"></div>
  <div data-id="row6" id="6"></div>
  <div data-id="row7" id="7"></div>
  <div data-id="row8" id="8"></div>
  <div data-id="row9" id="9"></div>
</div>

<button id="change">Chnage IDs</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what are you looking for?

```js
var elements = $('[data-id="row_34571"]');

$(elements.children('div').not(":first")).each(function(){
  $(this).attr("id","example");
  $(this).text("modified");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div id="test" data-id="row_34571">
    <div>Div 1</div>
    <div>Div 2</div>
    <div>Div 3</div>
    <div>Div 4</div>
  </div>
```